# Testing controller with configuration in play

Tags: playframework

I have the following controller which receives a config file:

```
class Demo @Inject() (config: Configuration) extends InjectedController {
```

In the test file I want to create an instance of the controller however I am not sure how to pass a configuration file to it:

```
private def controller = {
new Demo() {
  override def controllerComponents: ControllerComponents = Helpers.stubControllerComponents()
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

1. A class the uses the configuration, and then inject it to the controller/model class. For now lets say our class is `ServiceConfiguration` that holds the values from `application.conf`.
2. In your test you use `Guice` injection and `GuiceOneAppPerSuit` to have an app and inject the class of `Configuration`.

For example your test file for `Demo` class will be something like this:

```
class DemoSpec extends GuiceOneAppPerSuit { //with whatever other trait you want to bind in, like PlaySpec, Matchers, etc. 
  val injector: Injector = app.injector
  val conf = injector.instanceOf(classOf[ServiceConfiguration])

  // Your tests 
}
```

**Note**: You don't want to have a kitchen sink of configuration all in one place. You can have different classes for different configurations; and then inject them to their related controller/model classes and their related test classes.